# Getting web3 0.20.3 (Same as MetaMask)

Tags: web3js

When creating a site with MetaMask, you also want that other users who do not have MetaMask can use this site. To do this, you want to use the same library MetaMask uses - which is 0.20.3 currently.

I cannot find 0.20.3. I checked GitHub releases. Version 1.0.0-beta is up, and older versions do not hit 0.20.3

Where can I find this web3 version?

Answer (score 1):

Metamask injects in the page web3 and you can use this one without including any web3 scripts in your page.

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

You can check for metamask and alert message to the user if he donesn't have.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    alert('Please install metamask', 'Metamask!');
}
```

Comment: I have this already, thanks. However, I want that people who do NOT have MetaMask installed also being able to use web3. This means that they can VIEW data in a contract, but not interact with it since they have not connected an account.

Comment: Ok then you can try with NPM. Type in terminal "npm install web3@0.20.1"

Comment: Neat, that works!

Comment: We want 1.0rc is it fine to use?